# Licensing options in India

Tags: license, india

I would like to know what are all the licensing options available to get started with Ham in India.

I live in Hyderabad, India any pointers towards local groups would be great.

Comment: We welcome basic questions here, but they need to be questions that can be answered specifically. This question is too broad and has too many different parts. An example of a narrower question you could ask, that is part of this question, is “What types of amateur radio license exist in India, and who do I contact to get one?”

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, modified question as per your comments.

Comment: Thanks! I've reopened the question since it is reasonably narrow now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing and tests vary per country.

Amateur radio in India:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_in_India

Licensing in India:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_licence_categories_in_India

I couldn't find any practice test questions for the Indian tests, but there are a lot of questions free on-line and in book form for the U.S. tests. You might figure out the equivalent U.S. test of the license you are interested in and practice with those questions. I imagine they are similar.